# Nature of the union of two topologies

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\Bbb R$ and let $\mathcal{T}$ consist of all sets of the form $U \cup S$ where $U$ is an open set for the usual Euclidean topology and $S \subseteq \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$.

I am struggling to understand how this is any different from simply being on $\Bbb R$. If I take the union of a set and its subset, I end up with the set.

I first thought this is just to confuse the audience, but then later on I am asked to show something which is clearly not true for just $\Bbb R$.

So, there must be a difference I am somehow missing. What is it?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you, I think I got it now. You could put the comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [Michael line](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/michael-line-basics/), a classical example. It’s the usual topology where we make all irrational points isolated, essentially. It’s still quite nice (hereditarily paracompact e.g.) but it’s quite different from the usual topology which has no isolated points at all. Also, it’s no longer separable.